# Not setting int when prompted by scanner

Tags: java

This is my code, and I am having trouble, idk why especially when this should be fairly simple. I want to prompt the user for a number and then set a globally declared int to that number. The "members" int is initialized to 0 and no matter what I try, when I print out the members, it says 0 even if I enter in a number > 0

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a scanner object
System.out.println("Enter amount of members"); // Prompt user

while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    sc.next();
    try {
        members = sc.nextInt(); // set entered value to members int
    } catch (Exception e) { // catch exceptions.
        System.out.println("Error please enter a number greater than 0");
        sc.nextLine(); // clear line to prevent infinite loop
    }
}

sc.nextLine(); // clear input
```

Comment: what is `sc.next();` doing?

Comment: also what is `sc.nextLine(); // clear line to prevent infinite loop` doing?

Comment: you ask user to give a mount value, then use `while(!sc.hasNextInt())` that ignore the Integer. I can't figure out what you want.

Comment: Even, when I remove that and the sc.nextLine()'s it still results in the members int being 0 when I print it out idk why it isn't working. I hhave it declared globally as public static int members = 0; I did remove the while loop I had over it, and it did work actually, however I want it to print the error message and prompt the user again if they don't enter a integer

Answer (score -2):

Use `sc.nextInt()` and `sc.hasNext()` for while loop condition.

```
while (sc.hasNext()){
   members = reader.nextInt();
   ...
}
```

Also, we do not use  `sc.nextLine();` to clear line.

You need to study more on how to use Scanner, 
[Java Scanner Continuous User input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201384/java-scanner-continuous-user-input)

Comment: Even, when I remove that and the sc.nextLine()'s it still results in the members int being 0 when I print it out idk why it isn't working. I hhave it declared globally as public static int members = 0;

Comment: I have edited the answer so that you can understand better

Comment: @Nick If you have got it, please mark my answer as correct :P